# Find the conjugacy class $O_{(234)}$ if $G=A_{4}$ is acting on itself by conjugation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions, permutation-cycles

> Find the conjugacy class $O_{(234)}$ if $G=A_{4}$ is acting on itself by conjugation.

I calculated $(x)(234)$ for all $x\in A_{4}$ and got the set $O_{(234)}=\left \{(234), (143), (142), (123), (132)\right \}$.

This is because $(1)(234) = (234)$, $(123)(234) = (143)$, $(132)(234) = (241) = (142)$, $(142)(234) = (321) = (123)$, and $(143)(234) = (132)$.

Am I missing anything or doing anything wrong?

Comment: Orbit-Stabilizer theorem tells you the size of conjugacy class needs to divide $\lvert A_4\rvert=12$.

Comment: Don't you need to calculate all $x(234)x^{-1}$ (not just $x(234)$).

Comment: @ChrisCuster Oh I see. Maybe this will really help me!

Comment: @ChrisCuster How would I compute $(12)(34)(234)((12)(34))^{-1}$?

Comment: $((12)(34))^{-1}=(12)(34)$.  Check what happens to each element,  moving from right to left.   You get $(143)$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster So for $1$, $1\to 2\to 3\to 4\to 4$? I don't know why I get $(421)$ if I just test $1,2,3$ starting from $(34)$ and ending at $(12)$...

Comment: In $(421)$ we have $1\to4$.  Not sure I follow you.  You need to test each of $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  Where did you get $(421)$?

Comment: @ChrisCuster This is what I did for $1$, please correct me if I am wrong: In $(12)(34)(234)(12)(34)$, starting with $1$ in $(34)$, it is still $1$, and then it becomes $2$ in $(12)$. Then it becomes $3$ in $(234)$. Then it becomes $4$ in $(34)$. Then it remainds $4$ in $(12)$. This is how I deduced that $1\to 4$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86684/discussion-between-chris-custer-and-numericalorange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $|A_4|=12$ it isn't too much work to explicitly write out all conjugations. A few checks for your work:

- As noted in the comments, the size of the conjugacy class needs to divide $|A_4|=12$.
- Cycle type is preserved by conjugation, so all elements of the conjugacy class are $3$-cycles.

A bit more thought gets you even further; as there are precisely eight $3$-cycles in $A_4$, there are at most eight conjugates. As the conjugacy classes partition the $3$-cycles and $S_4$ acts transitively on them (because it acts transitively on $3$-cycles), the size of the conjugacy classes must also divide $8$. So the number of conjugates divides $\gcd(8,12)=4$.

Alternatively, by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, as the subgroup generated by $(2\ 3\ 4)$ clearly stabilizes $(2\ 3\ 4)$, and this subgroup contains $3$ elements, there are at most $\frac{|A_4|}{|\langle(2\ 3\ 4)\rangle|}=\frac{12}{3}=4$ conjugates.

Comment: Thanks! I realized I have to remove an element from my set in order for it to divide $|A_{4}|$. But I am not sure which element to remove?

Comment: Do the computations and you will see for yourself. You should be able to do such a computation with certainty yourself. If you are unsure, share your computations and I can try to point out a mistake if there is one.

Comment: I feel like the element $(123)$ should be removed, but does $(124)=(142)$?

Comment: You can write out how $(1\ 2\ 4)$ and $(1\ 4\ 2)$ act on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and see that they are different. Or note that $(1\ 2\ 4)(1\ 2\ 4)=(1\ 4\ 2)$ and so they cannot be equal. By the looks of it either $(1\ 2\ 3)$ or $(1\ 3\ 2)$ should not be in the conjugacy class, but I can't be bothered to check.